# remove empty cells in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, cells

I want to remove all empty cells at the bottom of a matlab cell array. However all code example that I found collapse the matrix to a vector, which is not what I want.

So this code

```
a = { 1, 2; 3, 4; [], []}
emptyCells = cellfun('isempty', a); 
a(emptyCells) = []
```

results in this vector

> a = [1]    [3]    [2]    [4]

But I want instead this array

> a =
>
> ```
> [1]    [2]
>
> [3]    [4]
> ```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want to delete all the rows in your cell array where all cell are empty, you can use the follwing:

```
a = { 1, 2; 3, 4; [], []}
emptyCells = cellfun('isempty', a); 

a(all(emptyCells,2),:) = []

a = 
    [1]    [2]
    [3]    [4]
```

The reason it didn't work in your formulation is that if you index with an array, the output is reshaped to a vector (since there is no guarantee that entire rows or columns will be removed, and not simply individual elements somewhere).

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
a = { 1, 2; 3, 4; [], []};
emptyCells = cellfun('isempty', a);
cols = size(a,2);
a(emptyCells) = [];
a = reshape(a, [], cols);
```

but I'm not sure if it will be general enough for you - will you always have complete rows of empty cells at the bottom of your array?

Comment: Currently yes, but in general I can no be sure. I was also thinking of using reshape, but in the end I used a simple search for the last row with is not empty, because I find the code you posted too complex or the acutal task.

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that generalizes the removing specific row/columns from a cell, which is called [`fun_removecellrowcols`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/46196-fun-removecellrowcols). Due to the removal, cell dimensions are resized.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution very specific to your problem is to convert the cell directly into a matrix:

```
cleanedA = cell2mat(a);
```

It converts to a normal matrix, and while doing this it removes the empty cells.

Then, of course, you can reconvert it to a cell array with the following command:

```
a = mat2cell(cleanedA, [1 1], [1 1])
```

Its not generic, but for the example posted it is the simplest solution I can think of.

Comment: Actually my cell array consists mainly of strings, so cell2mat is not useful for me.